# Why is the error message for failed logins to open.stackexchange.com, "Not Found"?

Tags: discussion, openid, stack-exchange-openid

The error message for failed logins to http://openid.stackexchange.com/ is, in its entirety:

```
Not Found
This page could not be found.
```

This is not a very good error message.